# Cleaning up after AJAX function in custom React hook

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-hooks

I've written a custom React hook that uses jQuery to fetch results from a given URL via AJAX (this is in the context of a legacy application, hence the need to use jQuery for AJAX), the API for which is loosely inspired by [axios-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hooks). The code for this is as follows (note it includes Flow annotations):

```
//@flow
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import type { jquery } from "jquery";

declare var $: jquery;

function useAjaxGet(url: string) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "json"
    }).done((data) => {
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
      setError(false);
    }).fail(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setError(true);
    });
  }, [url]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [url, fetchData]);

  return [{
    data: data,
    loading: loading,
    error: error
  }, fetchData];
}

export default useAjaxGet;
```

Now, this works for simple applications, but sooner or later it throws the following error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

I understand the fact that I have to return a cleanup function, and that the failure to do so is causing a memory leak. However, I'm struggling to understand what I can do to clear it up in this case. Can anyone throw any light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to cleanup the component. The main concept is simple: you **shouldnt update the state in an umount react element**.

### Solution 1: Avoiding to update the state manually using an `isMount` variable

```js
  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    let isMounted = true
    setLoading(true);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "json"
    }).done((data) => {
      // Before updating the state, check if the element has been unmounted while waiting
      if (!isMounted) {
        return;
      }
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
      setError(false);
    }).fail(() => {
      // Same, check if the element has been unmounted while waiting
      if (!isMounted) {
        return;
      }
      setLoading(false);
      setError(true);
    });
    // Cleanup function
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [url]);
```

You can see this solution on [Facebook's Relay Docs](https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/step-by-step#23-fetching-graphql-from-react).

[Demo using isMounted](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-bas-mzqzk?file=/src/App.js)

### Solution 2: Cancelling the request on unmount lifecycle (AJAX jQuery)

This will avoid the execution of all callbacks of the promise. Much cleaner! (Following example uses jQuery v3)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      xhr: function() {
        return xhr;
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      setState(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    return () => {
      xhr.abort(); // Cancel the request on unmount
    };
  }, [url]);
```

[Demo using Ajax request cancel](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-feather-m6rfk?file=/src/App.js)

### Solution 3: Cancelling the request on unmount lifecycle (fetch)

Same as Solution 2, but using `fetch`, since the usage is higher.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;
    fetch(url, { signal })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        setState(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [url]);
```

[Demo using AbortController](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-shirley-bvd20)

Comment: That doesn't look *quite* right. The principle, I think is sound, but the cleanup function needs to be returned from the `useEffect` hook call.

Comment: Its up to you to choose `useEffect` or `useCallback`. The concept is the same, not updating an unmounted element. Here you have an example by own Facebook: https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/step-by-step#23-fetching-graphql-from-react

Comment: OK. Doesn't seem to work with `useCallback`, but swapping to `useEffect` makes it work, so I'll mark that as accepted. Thanks very much!

Comment: Strange, I will review the behaviour in `useCallback`

Comment: @MatthewDaly Hey Ive implemented an `useCallback` and didnt get any issues: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-poitras-66hhj?file=/src/App.js. Also, Ive added another solutions cancelling the request instead of avoiding changing the state. Much cleaner IMO. Theorically this way is also possible in jQuery using `xhr.abort()` but didnt manage to make it work yet :/

Comment: @MatthewDaly Hey finally managed to make it work using jQuery. Check Solution 2 in the answer.

Comment: Nice one! That is a lot cleaner